# scala map get keys from Map as Sequence sorting by both keys and values

Tags: python, scala, sorting, dictionary

In Python I can do:

```
in_dd = {"aaa": 1, "bbb": 7, "zzz": 3, "hhh": 9, "ggg": 10, "ccc": 3}
out_ll = ['ggg', 'hhh', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc', 'zzz']
```

so, I want to get keys sorted by value in descending order while having keys in ascending order taking into consideration sorted values

How can I do it in Scala?

In Scala I know I can do:

```
val m = Map("aaa" -> 3, "bbb" -> 7, "zzz" -> 3, "hhh" -> 9, "ggg" -> 10, "ccc" -> 3)
m.toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
```

but I do not know how to sort by two cases.

EDIT:

I have tried also such approach but it does not return desired result:

```
m.toSeq.sortWith((x,y) => x._2 > y._2 && x._1 < y._1).map(_.1)
List((ggg,10), (hhh,9), (bbb,7), (ccc,3), (zzz,3), (aaa,3))
```

notice it shall be aaa,ccc,zzz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala you could use:

```
m.toSeq.sortBy(a => (a._2, a._1) )(Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering.Int.reverse, Ordering.String.reverse))
```

for `List((ggg,10), (hhh,9), (bbb,7), (zzz,3), (ccc,3), (aaa,3))`

and

```
m.toSeq.sortBy(a => (-a._2, a._1) )
```

for `List((ggg,10), (hhh,9), (bbb,7), (aaa,3), (ccc,3), (zzz,3))`

Comment: m.toSeq.sortBy(a => (a._2, a._1) )(Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering.Int.reverse, Ordering.String)) << THIS DOES THE JOB FOR ME. THANK YOU

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki See edit for order change.